# Compare 2 Tcl_Objs

Tags: c, tcl

Now to compare 2 `Tcl_Objs`, I extract the 2 strings and compare with each other like this :

```
const char* str1 = Tcl_GetString(myObj1);
const char* str2 = Tcl_GetString(myObj2);
if (!strcmp(str1 , str2)) {
    // do something
}
```

Instead of doing this, is there a way to compare the two objects directly with Tcl API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, [the internal `TclStringCmp` function](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/e3e5fcc0a8a3786dfa4a405e91610fc3c8d6c2e8/generic/tclStringObj.c#L3468-L3476) basically does the same thing: calls `Tcl_GetUnicodeFromObj` or `Tcl_GetStringFromObj` on the objects and `memcmp`s them.

Comment: The main thing that function does that you can't easily do with the public API is it avoids converting between the various internal string types when not necessary.